# A property similar to countable tightness

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am interested in topological spaces having the following property:

> A function $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if the restriction $f|_C$ is continuous for every countable subspace $C$ of $X$.

What are such spaces called? Have they been studied? I'd be grateful for any pointers.

---

This property is, to some extent, similar to countable tightness. If the above condition would characterize continuity of functions from $X$ to arbitrary space $Y$ instead of $\mathbb R$, then we would get spaces with countable [tightness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_%28topology%29); also known as [countably generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_generated_space) spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have seen this in either McCoy, Ntantu: topological properties of spaces of continuous functions, and/or in Arhangel'skij's book on $C_p(X)$, the latter calls it $t_\mathbb{R}$ as a cardinal function IIRC. Something like real-tightness. So $t_{\mathbb{R}}(X) \le \tau$ iff ($f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff its restriction to all subsets of cardinality $\le \tau$ of $X$ is continuous).

I think it corresponds to some cardinal invariant of $C_p(X)$ and that this was the reason for its introduction. I don't have access to these books now, so I cannot check exactly, but I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that on [p.58](http://books.google.com/books?id=nl3mFq7FzNcC&pg=PA58) of the Arkhangelskii's book Topological Function Spaces the notion of *functional tightness* is defined. He gives also reference to [this paper](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106209).

Comment: Ah, my memory not completely useless... A countably tight space is just the same as a hereditarily functionally countably tight space (all Tychonoff), as Arhangel'skij proves later on in that book.

Comment: In McCoy, Ntantu: *Topological Properties of Spaces of Continuous Functions* they define functional tightness on p.72-73. An additional reference to this [Uspenskii's paper](https://eudml.org/doc/17234) is given there. Here is an [alternative link](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106210).

Comment: The Uspenskij paper shows part of its motivation: $X$ realcompact iff $C_p(X)$ is functionally countably tight. Interesting stuff.